# Как заблокировать ввод времени в maskedtextbox раньше чем текущего времени?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть maskedtextbox, где вводится время работы (формат "час:минута"). Как заблокировать ввод времени раньше текущего времени?
Вот что есть на данный момент:

```
        uint b;
        time.BackColor = Color.White;
        prov = uint.TryParse(time.Text, out b);
        if (prov == false)
            time.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала можно использовать `DateTime` для хранения времени, если конечно это не противоречит вашей основной задаче, о которой вы ни чего не написали.

В случае использования `DateTime`, решение будет выглядеть так:

```
DateTime userTime;
time.BackColor = Color.White;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(time.Text, out userTime) || userTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now) < new TimeSpan())
    time.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Этот же прием подойдет для проверки с учетом даты. Для тестирования приема можете воспользоваться примером для консольного приложения с подробным выводом:

```
System.DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out date);
System.TimeSpan diff = date.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(diff < new TimeSpan());
Console.WriteLine(diff.ToString());
```

Comment: Да я пытался использовать DateTime вместе с TimeSpan, но не получалось их вместе заставить работать. Возникал тот же случай что и сейчас. Вот здесь
|| userTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now < new TimeSpan()
пишет "Оператор "<" невозможно применить к операнду типа DateTime и TimeSpan".

Comment: забыл одну скобочку закрыть, поправил. `DateTime.Substract()` возвращает `TimeSpan`, так что сравнение будет работать

Comment: Понятно как это теперь делается. Благодарю за ответ!